# How do I improve JPG export quality in TikzEdt?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, export

I'm a brand new user of TikzEdt (v0.2.3.0), which came up in my search for a tool to produce publication-quality circuit diagrams.

Along with Circuitikz, this seems like it might be a viable solution.  That said, I'm getting some pretty cruddy JPG exports.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,4) to [voltage source, v_ =\LARGE $5\ V$, i=\LARGE $i\ {=}\ \frac{5\ V}{100\ \Omega}\ {=} 50\ mA$
  ] (0,0);
\draw (0,4) --  (6,4) to [resistor=\LARGE $100 \  \Omega$
] (6,0)
-- (0,0)    ; 
\draw (0,0) to  (0,-.5
) node[ground, label =right:\Large$GND$ ]{};


  \end{tikzpicture}
```

yields

[image]

which is obviously pretty cruddy.  My WYSIWYG previews and PDF outputs are very nice, but these aren't.

Other export options yield similar results.  I tried exporting an SVG output, but TikzEdt seems to choke on that, giving me a "compiling for export" line that never terminates.

In any case, I know the difference between raster and vector graphics, and I've adjusted JPG compression in different applications, but I can't find any options to control compression.  The only "save as.." option is PDF, with no postscript choice available.

Is there a way to generate a high-quality output?  JPG is preferable, but anything I can open and convert in Gimp would be fine.

Comment: Why can't you use PDF? Or even include the code directly in your main document?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Simply tool choices, and the project I'm on will be passed around to quite a few people, and I don't want to dictate the tool chain to others.   Also, I'm not comfortable enough in the environment to commit to signing on for a very large project (of which circuit diagrams are a rather small, but important part).

Comment: Will the image files be edited by others? If not, I struggle to see why PDF isn't an option (though of course, I don't know how the project is set up, so there is probably something I'm not considering).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- no, the images will not be edited, but I've never had any luck getting Word to play nicely with inserted pdf objects.

Comment: Ah, Word. Didn't occur to me that you were using that. How about converting the PDF to EPS?

Comment: That might actually do it.  Using Gimp to do the import, it seems like I need to up the resolution (which defaults at 100dpi), and then export it with light compression.   The jpg comes out pretty good.   I can probably write a macro to do it. Seems like a long way to go, but at least I know this isn't a non-starter.

Comment: Can't Word use EPS files directly?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - yes, but TikzEdt isn't giving me a way to create the EPS.

Comment: I meant of course to convert the PDF from TikZEdt directly to EPS, and use that in Word.

Comment: Please don't use jpg! For such graphics at least use png to avoid halo-effect and allow use of transparency. If tikzedt is not capable of producing png, try qtikz/ktikz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG is *not* a recommended export format for vector graphics. Its compression is lossy and its purpose is storing photographs. Export vector graphics to PNG instead (if you need it in a bitmap format).

PDF to PNG, using `convert` from ImageMagick.org:

```
   pdflatex example
   pdflatex example
   convert -density 300 example.pdf example.png
```

For publishing on the Web, conversion to SVG is another option:

```
   latex example
   latex example
   dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff --exact  example
```

[image]

File `example.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,4) to [voltage source, v_ =\LARGE $5\ V$, i=\LARGE $i\ {=}\ \frac{5\ V}{100\ \Omega}\ {=} 50\ mA$] (0,0);
  \draw (0,4) --  (6,4) to [resistor=\LARGE $100 \  \Omega$] (6,0) -- (0,0);
  \draw (0,0) to  (0,-.5) node[ground, label =right:\Large$GND$ ]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scale=val` option of `tikz` to scale the pic and then `export` it as jpg or some other image format.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20]

%tikzpicture code here

\end{tikzpicture}
```